# Is "has been to overlook" correct English?

Tags: grammar

The whole sentence is:

> The error of modern atheism **has been to overlook** how many aspects of the faiths remain relevant even after their central tenets have been dismissed.

I did not understand the grammar structure of 'has been to overlook...'. Not sure if this is correct English. This sentence was excerpted from a native English author Alain de Botton's book. Could anyone explain this grammatical usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your sentence, `"to overlook how many aspects of the faiths remain relevant even after their central tenets have been dismissed"` is a **to-infinitive clause** which serves as **a subject complement** and according to Cambridge Dictionary it [means](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-words-clauses-and-sentences/subject-complements):

> A subject complement gives us more information about the subject. It
>   usually comes after linking verbs and sense verbs (including be, seem,
>   smell, taste), and after change of state verbs (including go, get,
>   become).

In your sentence "has been" is the present perfect form of the verb *"to be"* which is a linking verb and can be followed by a subject complement in order to give more information about the subject of your sentence (*The error of modern atheism*).

Comment: great, I think you are probably right. However, I still feel that if author changes "has been" to "has become", this sentence will be much more readable. :)

Comment: @Dave Hwang: Nah - if you simply replaced ***to overlook*** in the cited text with ***overlooking***, you'd effectively end up with a somewhat gibberish sentence. You can't really say "the error" actually ***does*** something like "overlooking", but you can certainly *define* that error using an infinitive construction as cited.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, yes, just realized that. So I edited my words soon. :)

Comment: +1 to the answer.  @Dave Hwang: **has become** is complemented by an attained state; *to overlook* something is not a state but an action.   *They have become **entangled** in a scandal.*